# Toggling is-loading of an LWC search input?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html

The `<lightning-input type="search"></lightning-input>` has the `is-loading` attribute that puts a little spinner in it 'when data is loading'.

For my search input, I call out to Apex with the search term and return record that match or partially match the search term with their name. However, I cannot find a way to turn this is-loading on and off. I am not seeing how you dynamically toggle this attribute.

I am wanting to do something like:

```
this.isLoading = true;
searchObjects({objectType: this.objectType, phrase: searchPhrase})
            .then(result => {
                this.results= JSON.parse(result);
                this.isLoading = false;

            }).catch(error => {
                this.isLoading = false;
                //show error
            });
```

Where `isLoading` will toggle the is-loading attribute of the input. Is this possible?

Comment: Just tested this, and yes, it should work. Your problem might be elsewhere. Can we see more code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to set the attribute, then you can toggle it. [Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/s1v5-tji/1/edit).

```
<lightning-input label="Search" is-loading={isLoading} type="search"></lightning-input>
```

...

```
@track isLoading = false;
```

...

```
this.isLoading = true;
searchObjects({objectType: this.objectType, phrase: searchPhrase})
            .then(result => {
                this.results = result;
            }).catch(error => {
                //show error
            }).finally(() => this.isLoading = false);
```

Comment: Oh nice. I couldn't find an example of actually setting it, only it existing in the component to indicate it was loading. Then I was playing around in the playground by setting it to `"false"` in the HTML and it didn't do anything, the spinner was still there, so assumed it couldn't be set. Then when I tried your example with the @track it works. A bit confusing, but at least it works this way. Thank you.